# Fetched data from external api,how to loop through the array and display values

Tags: reactjs, redux, mapping, store

> "    I made a call to externalapi using react redux and store is loaded with data from API.But when I am trying to use map function"Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" error is displayed

```
     {this.props.carDetails.array.map(([key,value])=>[key,value])}

carDetails is loaded with following dat

    open_cars: Array(2)
    0: {carid: 1, title: “bmw”} 1: {carid:2,title:”audi”}"


Here is my class
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { fetchVehicleDetails } from '../actions'
import Post from '../components/Post/Post.js'
class FetchRandomUser extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchVehicleDetails()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.carDetails.array.map(([key, value]) => [key, value])}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
FetchRandomUser.propTypes = {
  // carDetails:PropTypes.object,
  fetchVehicleDetails: PropTypes.func
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    carDetails: state.carDetails
  }
}
function loadData(store) {
  return store.dispatch(fetchVehicleDetails())
}
export default {
  loadData,
  component: connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchVehicleDetails })((FetchRandomUser))
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: You should do a log on props: `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props,udefined,2))` I think you're probably trying to access response data before it's been set.

Comment: I could see the data coming into carDetails,but I am unable to loop through and display values. CarDetails has the following data open_cars: Array(2)
    0: {carid: 1, title: “bmw”} 1: {carid:2,title:”audi”}"

Answer (score 0):

Because when you fetch data from API server, this is an **async**. When your Component render the first time, `carDetails` ***not yet updated***. In the next render of Component (the second time), `carDetails` ***will be updated.***

So, in your component, check like this:

```
class FetchRandomUser extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchVehicleDetails()
  }
  render() {
    const { carDetails } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {
           // The data: `open_cars: Array(2) 0: {carid: 1, title: “bmw”} 1: {carid:2,title:”audi”}"`
           // So you must access to `open_cars` not `array` here
           carDetails && carDetails.open_cars && carDetails.open_cars.length && 
           carDetails.open_cars.map(([key,value])=>[key,value])
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this way but didn't work throwing same error :(

Comment: The error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` has mean attr `array` is undefined. Are you sure you have attr `.array` as Array in `carDetails` ?

Comment: I editted my post. Please try again ! You should access to your key is `open_cars`, not `array as type Array`

Comment: When I used the following code I was able to view data..Thank a lot :) .  {
  carDetails && carDetails.open_cars && 
  carDetails.open_cars.map((item,i)=>
    <li key ={i}>
    {item.title}</li>
    )
}

Answer (score 0):

What I can guess from here is you are not mapping over the array 
Change your map as

```
{this.props.carDetails.open_cars.map((value)=>value)}
```

Considering you do have an array in open_cars.
If this is an object you can use Object.keys(yourObject).map() to loop over properties in an object.

Comment: I tried this but error is thrown showing up as open_cars is undefined

Comment: why are you mapping on this.props.carDetails.array ? can you show what does this.props.carDetails logs ?

Answer (score 0):

You are reading "this.props.carDetails.array", where in the response you have "
    open_cars: Array(2)".
But you are accessing "this.props.carDetails.array.map" where the "array" is not in actual response.

So try like this.

```
    <div>
        {this.props.carDetails && this.props.carDetails.open_cars ?
this.props.carDetails.open_cars.map(([key, value]) => [key, value])
:'' }
      </div>
```